# Best practices for importing leads and contacts from trade shows

Tags: duplicate-management, merge, data-import

I'm the new manager of a mid-size Salesforce org for a company that has some presence at industry tradeshows. At the end of each show, there's always a list of leads to be imported into a campaign.

Because of the nature of our business, it's very common that this list contains records for people we already know about in salesforce as leads or contacts, and naturally we'd like to merge new records with existing ones to avoid creating unnecessary duplicates.

How have you been handling this?

I see a few options:

a. importing them all as leads into a campaign and running a de-duping tool (we have Cloudingo) on them, first trying to match to existing contacts, then to leads, finally making new leads

b. using a lead import package like Leadly

c. writing a custom lead import tool using the salesforce enterprise API to implement custom logic (I'm a developer and already work with the API quite a bit)

Thanks!
- Andrew

Comment: I use the standard Salesforce duplicate management tool. It gives option to block /allow duplicate records. Also, you can have a report on possible duplicates.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=5

Btw if you are using spreadsheets to store leads in the first place y are doing something fundamentally wrong. CRM is made to move people away from spreadsheets. Use Web-lead, or custom lead ui to input leads faster

Comment: Thanks for the reply - we're going with the Cloudingo solution here. As for the spreadsheets, the tradeshows we go to have a standardized lead acquisition system that delivers data to us as spreadsheets, so this is a perfectly legit CRM use case.